# How to add many line in Time Series Chart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add another line in the time series chart. And currently I did not find anyway to do this. I am using `chart_flutter` dependencies.

Here is my chart code look like:

```
charts.TimeSeriesChart(
                  series,
                  animate: true,
                  defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(
                    includeArea: true,
                    includeLine: true,
                  ),
                  dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
                  behaviors: [
                    charts.PanAndZoomBehavior(),
                    charts.SeriesLegend(
                      position: charts.BehaviorPosition.top,
                      horizontalFirst: false,
                      cellPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, top: 10, bottom: 4.0),
                    ),
                    charts.SelectNearest(
                      eventTrigger: charts.SelectionTrigger.tap
                    ),
                    charts.LinePointHighlighter(
                      symbolRenderer: CustomCircleSymbolRenderer(size: size),
                    ),
                  ],
                  selectionModels: [
                    charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                    type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
                    changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
                      if(model.hasDatumSelection) {
                        final tankVolumeValue = model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index).round();
                        final dateValue = model.selectedSeries[0].domainFn(model.selectedDatum[0].index);
                        CustomCircleSymbolRenderer.value = '$dateValue \n $tankVolumeValue';
                    }
                  })
                ]),
```

Any idea on how to add another line is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above is simply that you can add more data in the variable that hold the data. Like below:

```
charts.Series(
          id: 'Tank 1',
          data: some data here,
          colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
          domainFn: (TankPing ping, _) => some data,
          measureFn: (TankPing ping, _) => some data
        ),
charts.Series(
              id: 'Tank 1',
              data: some data here,
              colorFn: (_, __) => MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
              domainFn: (TankPing ping, _) => some data,
              measureFn: (TankPing ping, _) => some data
            )
```

Comment: Can you expand on this because I cannot see how this works with this example

Comment: Hi there @AndrewThompson, sorry but this is an old Code and I did not maintain this code anymore. Probably can you refer to the doc incase they explain how to add more chart lines.

Basically, all you have to do is just add `charts.Series()` either in loop or as a component if based on the code that I post above. 

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for replying.  It had escaped me that the charts take an array of series arrays.  So it is quite possible to have multiple series.  I have sorted it now.